# Data Scraping: Javascript Returning data:image/svg Instead of URL

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, tampermonkey

I've been building a tampermonkey script in order to download images from a certain nsfw website. Everything seemed to work wonderfully a few days ago, but now I'm having a problem where instead of the image src being scraped, it is returning a data:image/svg.

Specifically this one:
`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20200%20100'%2F%3E`

The website (nubiles) has 12 images per page, and it seems random on which urls are converted to this data. I've tried both jquery and javascript, but keep getting the same outcome.

Here is the function from my script.

```js
Mousetrap.bind('shift+i', function(e) {
        var seriesTitle = 'Bratty Sis';
        $('.content-grid-item.col-12.col-sm-6.col-lg-4').each(function(i, div) {
            //var imageUrl = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src').replace('cover960', 'cover1280'); //Large landscape photo.
            var imageUrl = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src').replace('cover960', 'cover614'); //Portrait photo.
            console.log(imageUrl);
            var id = $(this).find('.lazy.content-grid-image').attr('tube_tour_thumb_id');
            var title = $(this).find('.title').text().trim();
            var startTitle = toTitleCase(title.split('-')[0]);
            var endTitle = title.split('-')[1].replace(' ', '').replace(':', '');
            var sceneDate = moment($(this).find('.date').text()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var imageName = seriesTitle + ' ' + sceneDate + ' ' + id + ' ' + startTitle + '[' + endTitle + '].jpg';

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var a = document.createElement('a'); // create html element anchor
                a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);  // xhr.response is a blob
                a.download = imageName; // Set the file name.
                a.style.display = 'none'; // set anchor as hidden
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();
            };
            xhr.onerror= function(e) {
                alert("Error fetching " + url);
            };
            //xhr.open('GET', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + imageUrl);
            //xhr.send();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Does anyone know why it would be doing this at random?
Also, a side question. When it does actually run properly, it only downloads 10 images. Is this a limit with XMLHttpRequest or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It appears as though its giving you back an element div.

`data:image/svg xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 200 100'/>`

maybe you need to dig one down deeper to make sure you get an image url. need to parse the elements to make sure they are giving what you need.

Comment: Thank you, that indirectly got me to my answer. Turns out the website was lazy loading the last row of images. Does explain why it would show as a div instead of the img. Is there any chance you know why only the first 10 XMLHttpRequest's are being sent?

Comment: Most lazy-loaders wait until an image is in view before loading. One trick is to scroll to the bottom of the page. Maybe look at document.images.length and use window.scrollBy(0,10000) to get to the end of the page.